# Прогрессбар при респонсиве неправильно считает ширину

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, адаптивная-верстка

Оригинальный код и пример работы [здесь](http://codepen.io/sharedhare/pen/qZpWjL).

Не могу сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении экрана браузера:

1. Прогресс-бар не уползал вправо.
2. Исправить неправильную калькуляцию. Поскольку хочу сделать адаптивную верстку, ширина `label` плавающая, я не знаю как реализовать. На что, какие события повесить?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.progressbar').each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var dataperc = t.attr('data-perc'),
      barperc = Math.round(dataperc * 5.56);
    t.find('.progressbar__bar').animate({
      width: barperc
    }, dataperc * 25);
    t.find('.label').append('<div class="perc"></div>');

    function perc() {
      var length = t.find('.progressbar__bar').css('width'),
        perc = Math.round(parseInt(length) / 5.65),
        labelpos = (parseInt(length) - 2);
      t.find('.label').css('left', labelpos);
      t.find('.perc').text(perc + '%');
    }
    perc();
    setInterval(perc, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 560px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.progressbar:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 558px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #eeeef0;
}
.progressbar__bar {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 22px;
  background: #35373e;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progressbar__bar:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 606px;
  height: 150%;
  top: -25%;
  left: -25px;
}
.progressbar__bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 64px;
  height: 16px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.progressbar__bar span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.progressbar .label {
  font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #acafba;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div data-perc="100" class="progressbar">
        <div class="progressbar__bar"><span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="label"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-perc="50" class="progressbar">
        <div class="progressbar__bar"><span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="label"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-perc="30" class="progressbar">
        <div class="progressbar__bar"><span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="label"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените фиксированную ширину прогрессбара (.progressbar) на процентную и в функции расчёта ширины полоски прогресса (.progressbar__bar) также назначайте процентную ширину.

```js
$('.progress__bar').each(function() {
  $progess = $(this);
  
  $progess.animate({
    width: $(this).data('completed') + '%'
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.progress__bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.progress__bar:after {
  content: attr(data-completed)'%';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__bar" data-completed="25"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__bar" data-completed="50"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__bar" data-completed="75"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```